# Android JSON Parser From URL (NON DEPECREATED)

Tags: android, json, android-studio

Okay I'm coming close to my wits end here. I have been following code samples and reading threads on how to hit a URL and read in the JSON object following that web request. But these samples all seem to use HttpClient and HttpResponse which android studio is saying is deprecated. Android API says to use URL Connection, but I can't seem to understand how to use the pattern with URLConnection.

So how do I use URLConnection to hit a URL, and then read the JSON objects. I can deserialize myself later as JSONObject is NOT deprecated. I am struggling on how to initiate the web request.

Anyone have code snippets? Samples? Material available online?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html start from here

Comment: @Downvoters, please explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/HURL) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android), here is a thread that loads the latest Stack Overflow [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) questions using `HttpURLConnection` and parses them using Gson:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2013-2014 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.hurl;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import de.greenrobot.event.EventBus;

class LoadThread extends Thread {
  static final String SO_URL=
      "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?"
          + "order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&tagged=android";

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      HttpURLConnection c=
          (HttpURLConnection)new URL(SO_URL).openConnection();

      try {
        InputStream in=c.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader=
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        SOQuestions questions=
            new Gson().fromJson(reader, SOQuestions.class);

        reader.close();

        EventBus.getDefault().post(new QuestionsLoadedEvent(questions));
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception parsing JSON", e);
      }
      finally {
        c.disconnect();
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception parsing JSON", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `SOQuestions` is the Gson-annotated class for the Stack Exchange questions API, and I am using greenrobot's EventBus to get the results over to a fragment. Of course, you would replace the Stack Exchange API URL with your own and would need to parse whatever its JSON output is.

I'm not aware of many Android developers using `JSONObject` anymore, given much better options in Gson, Jackson, etc., but you would need to read in the `InputStream` into a `String` to pass to the appropriate `JSONObject` constructor.

You might also consider using higher-order approaches. For example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/Retrofit) is a clone of the first that uses Square's Retrofit library for contacting the Stack Exchange API Web service, rather than `HttpUrlConnection`.

Comment: what is the difference between Gson and Json ?

Comment: @Arlind: JSON is a data format. [Google's Gson](https://github.com/google-gson/google-gson) is a library for parsing JSON.